# Get the classname from multi class element which has underscore

Tags: jquery, regex

I have an element like the following:

```
<div class="busatt bus_12_1">data</div>   //classname->bus_databasevalue1_databasevalue2
```

I need to get the class that has underscore in it.I cannot put this classname as ID name because it can be duplicated sometimes.

I need it something like this.

```
$('busatt').prop('class').match(some regex exp) should give me only ''bus_12_1'' .
```

I know that ,we can get the classname like following:

```
  var classes = $('busatt').prop('class').split(' ');
  for(var i=0; i<classes.length; i++){
         if( classes[i].indexOf('_') != -1 )
         {
           alert(classes[i]);
         }
  }
```

Can I get the result in a single line of code with regex or something like

Comment: `$('.busatt').filter(function() { return /\bbus_\d+_\d+\b/i.test($(this).attr('class')); });` assuming that the classname always contains the two numbers. I'll suggest to use the `data-*` attributes to store custom data on HTML elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#expr) function to reduce the set of matched elements.
this is a small demo:

```js
$("div").filter(function() {
        return this.className.match(/\b\w*_\w*\b/);
    })
    .html("Matched!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="busatt bus_12_1">data</div>
```

EDIT BY TECHY:

I have used the following code and is working :

```
var new_class=''; 
new_class = $(this).prop('class').match(/\b\w*_\w*\b/).toString();
alert(new_class);
```

Comment: Note that it's a CSS selector and what OP wants is `$("*[class^='busatt'][class*='_'").className.match(/\b\w*_\w*\b/);`

Comment: @Mehdi Bouzidi I need to get the classname within a string for further requirements. You gave me the code for identification of the element with underscore..

Comment: @revo I added your `regex` to my edited answer, thanks it works !

Comment: I suggest using `\bbus_\d+_\d+\b` regex. Current regex even matches `balhfldjsalfjdlsajflds_fdsafdsa_fdsafdsa`. @Techy

Comment: Yes because OP needs *to get the class that has underscore in it*. @Tushar